# A few questions regarding CACHE MANIFEST syntax/limitations

Tags: browser, html, manifest

I could not find any answers to the following questions, so where better than to ask on StackOverflow? :)

1. Can I use full absolute URL's in my CACHE MANIFEST file?

   Example:

   ```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   http://www.example.com/css/stylesheet.css
   http://www.example.com/img/image.png
   ```
2. Will the browser cache files on a different domain than the origin if they are listed in the MANIFEST?

   Example:

   ```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   http://www.example.com/css/stylesheet.css
   http://www.exampleimages.com/img/image1.png
   http://www.exampleimages.com/img/image2.png
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, because of [Same-Origin constraints](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#appcache).